# Can't resolve all parameters for Page: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm building an Ionic Project and want to use an Injectable class `Requests` to manage globally available variables and methods.
I tried to inject this into the `LoginPage` but it throws the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginPage: (?). I've
>   removed some things from the sample code, that doesn't interfere with
>   the problem.

The weird thing is: The problem *only* appears when I use `LoginPage`
 anywhere in the `Requests` class. Even if the code is never used. I've marked it in the sample code.
**app.module.ts:**

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Requests } from '../providers/requests/requests';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    Requests,
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**Requests.ts:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';;
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login/login'

@Injectable()
export class Requests {
  constructor() {

  }

  public whatever(ret: any){
    ret.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    // Whenever i remove the line above, everything works fine.
    // This method isn't called at any time.
    // However, i need it to reference LoginPage here.
  }
}
```

**LoginPage.ts:**

```js
import { Requests } from '../../providers/requests/requests';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, MenuController, AlertController, 
LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {   

  constructor(public request: Requests) {}
}
```

I've tried to replicate this in a sample project but unfortunately wasn't able to. Do you have any suggestions for what to look for? Thank you.

Comment: this mainly happens when import modules are missing in app.component.ts file.  just recheck ur code because in ionic 4 NavParams are no longer used.

Comment: I'm not using Ionic 4.
Also the code doesn't even use NavParams etc.
I've rechecked my code multiple times.I don't have any idea of how to prevent this error other than removing LoginPage from the Requests class, which is extremely weird.

Comment: I think it's happen because that you have circular imports